# GDI+ Moving Line Memory Leak

Tags: vb.net, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, gdi+

I have tried to do this both with GDI+/Invalidate and by using a Line Shape Control.  In both cases the memory spirals out of control.  To demonstrate, create a windows form application with a timer object which is set to 100ms and enabled and use the following code:

```
Public Class Form1
   Private Y As Integer
   Private intDirection As Integer = 1

   Private Sub timTest_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles timTest.Tick
      Me.Invalidate()
   End Sub

   Private Sub Form1_Paint(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs) Handles Me.Paint

      Dim g As Graphics = Me.CreateGraphics
      Dim myPen As New Pen(Color.Black)

      myPen.Width = 1
      g.SmoothingMode = Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias
      g.DrawLine(myPen, 10, 10, 200, Y)

      Y += intDirection

      If Y > Me.Height - 20 Then intDirection = -1
      If Y < 0 Then intDirection = 1
      g.Dispose()
      myPen.Dispose()
   End Sub
End Class
```

So the code above causes a memory leak as the line moves.  I think the reason is that there are unmanaged bitmaps created behind the scenes to paint the form which are not being released because on the managed side it is just a pointer.

If I add the following code at the start of the paint function

```
  Dim intAlloc As Integer = Me.Width * Me.Height * 16
  GC.AddMemoryPressure(intAlloc)
```

and at the end of the function I call

```
  GC.RemoveMemoryPressure(intAlloc)
```

The memory utilization grows a little and shrinks a little but never grows out of control.  The AddMemoryPressure and RemoveMemoryPressure seems to alert the GC that it needs to run.  Is there a better way to do this or is this correct?  The code above is just a simplification for example purposes to get to the root of a problem I have in a larger component with several moving lines.  Also is this the best way to calculate the proper value to place in AddMemoryPressure?

Comment: Why are you calling Me.CreateGraphics() in your Paint method?  That could be part of your problem.  You should be using the Graphics instance that is passed into the paint event (e.Graphics)

Comment: After looking at Hans' answer below I sped up the timer and realized that the memory rise does stabilize eventually (though it does not come back down significantly).  However - it first grows to 2 to 3 times the size of utilization at launch.  That seems severe.  Which is why I was wondering if the Graphics engine was using unmanaged memory which we need to alert the GC of so that we clean it up in a more timely fashion.  Am I totally off base here and just need to ignore it and let GC do its thing?

Comment: Also - I mentioned it in a comment to Hans below.  But thank you for correcting me on the e.Graphics.  That is correct - though it did not seem to really affect the outcome of the test.

Comment: @Audio: not sure why this thread is still open.  Do you need something else?

Comment: @Hans:  See my comment from Jun 30 at 17:20 where I am still questioning whether the AddMemoryPressure should be used in this instance.  GC lets it grow to 2 or 3 times initial startup before stabilizing, and though it stabilizes it does not really come down.  That seems severe.  Should we be alerting the GC that the graphics engine may be using more than expected using AddMemoryPressure, or just tell customers that it will grow considerably and then level off and trust the GC?

Comment: @ Hans:  Your answer was fix your code - use e.Graphics.  While you are correct and I have donw that - It does not change how the app functions.  Memory utilization still spirals pretty severely before leveling off, and then it never really seems to comes down.  It looks bad to customers.  This looks like a place for AddMemoryPressure, but I could be wrong hence the original question.